# What is the color of material's UI default text field color?

Tags: reactjs, sass, material-ui

I have this datepicker and I wanted to have it the same border-bottom color with the textfield color of material-ui.

These are the codes in codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-wescoff-71z8u?file=/src/styles.scss

```
  <DatePicker
        wrapperClassName="datePicker"
        selected={startDate}
        onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)}
        showTimeSelect
        dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a"
        timeFormat="hh:mm a"
        timeIntervals={30}
      />
```

the styles.scss

```
.datePicker {
  grid-column: 5/10;
  grid-row: 2/4;
  padding-bottom: 50px;

  input {
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    background: transparent;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    &:focus {
      outline: none;
      border-bottom: 2px solid #f50057;
    }
  }
}
```

What is the color for the standard textfield of material-ui?

[image]

Comment: This: `.MuiInput-underline`. However It inherits from other base field such as `input` so try to change this following color code- `&:focus {
      outline: none;
      border-bottom: 2px solid #f50057;
    }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a color-picker tool, I found the color to be Hex #AFAFAF or RGB 175,175,175